# DoesNotExist at /accounts/login/ (delate example.com from admin page)

Tags: django, django-allauth

I'm trying to configure Django App.
I logged in to Django admin page and delated "example.com" from "Site".

After that, I can not access the admin page or login page.

Error message is here

> Exception Value: Site matching query does not exist. Exception
> Location: /home/app_admin/venv_ruling/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py,
> line 437, in get

Since I can not access admin page, I can not recover "example.com" as site.

How can I recover it??

I just mentioned the above settings in this question but still if more code is required then tell me I'll update my question with that information. Thank you

Comment: If you don't plan on using the sites framework to manage multiple sites you can remove `'django.contrib.sites'` from`INSTALLED_APPS`.

Comment: Alternatively create a new `Site` object from the Django shell and update the `SITE_ID` setting to match the id of the new site.